# Removing text from a string between Span element in VB.Net

Tags: regex, vb.net

I have strings which look like this:

```
%20-%20<span%20style=color:Red;>Pepsi%20Max</span>%20+%20£3%20Tip
```

and I wish to remove every existence of:

```
<span%20style=color:Red;>ANY TEXT</span>
```

completely from the string. So to clarify, the string may contain multiple text spans where the color is set to Red, and it's these I wish to remove so in this case the string would look like this:

```
%20-%20%20+%20£3%20Tip
```

I need to do this in VB.Net and really don't know where to start. Any help appreciated.

```
Dim orderSentence As String = Label1.Text

Dim shortenedOrderSentence As New Regex("<span%20style=color:Red;>.*<\/span>")
Dim str as string = shortenedOrderSentence.Replace(orderSentence, "")
Label1.text = str
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regular expression:

```
<span%20style=Red;>.*<\/span>
```

And replace it with empty string, you'll get what you want.
So with Regex class and your example:

```
Dim r As New Regex("<span%20style=Red;>.*<\/span>")
Dim str as string = r.Replace("%20-%20<span%20style=Red;>Pepsi%20Max</span>%20+%20£3%20Tip", "")
```

String variable will contains expected string.

EDIT:
Use in test page

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim orderSentence As String = "%20-%20<span%20style=color:Red;>Pepsi%20Max</span>%20+%20£3%20Tip"

    Context.Response.Write("Original string: ")
    Context.Response.Write(orderSentence)

    Context.Response.Write("<br /><br />")

    Dim shortenedOrderSentence As New Regex("<span%20style=color:Red;>.*<\/span>")

    Context.Response.Write("Result string: ")
    Context.Response.Write(shortenedOrderSentence.Replace(orderSentence, ""))
End Sub
```

Result in browser:

[image]

For decoded string (%20 is white char), use another regular expression, for example "<span\sstyle=color:Red;>.*</span>"

Comment: Yes, should have been Red, I've edited that now. Ah, so .* will work as a wildcard?

Comment: I edited answer. Dot with asterisk will work as any character, you will end it with left left angle bracket.

Comment: I've edited the initial question and incorporated what you've suggested here but still no luck. You can see better what I'm doing though. I've replace r with shortenedOrderSentence as r already exists in other nearby code. I've never used Regex before so this is all still new to me as I'm still learning. Thanks for any further help.

Comment: Also, should it not be </span> ?

Comment: No, it should be with escape slash, because "/" is special char. What text do you have in the label? Also mind a case sensitivity of regular expression...

Comment: I just tried Response.Redirect(Label1.Text) to see what's in there and it literally contains this: %20-%20<span%20style=color:Red;>Pepsi%20Max</span>%20+%20£3%20Tip

Comment: It works if I do:  shortenedOrderSentence.Replace("%20-%20<span%20style=Red;>Pepsi%20Max</span>%20+%20£3%20Tip", "") but not when I do shortenedOrderSentence.Replace(orderSentence, "")

Comment: So variable shortenedOrderSentence can't contains expample string. I edited answer again and I added next example. Try UrlDecode/UrlEncode function for getting original encoded string from the label...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229438/discussion-between-jaydee-and-mark-davies).

Comment: All working. Thanks JayDee. After adding /s to sort the %20 situation out, this works great!